# Python OptParse combine multiple options

Tags: python, optparse

Example code:

```
import optparse
import sys
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage='python %prog -t -b -q',
                           prog=sys.argv[0],
                           )
parser.add_option('-t','--tt', action="store_true", help="Blah",dest="t")

parser.add_option('-b','--bb', action="store_true", help="Blah",dest="b")

parser.add_option('-q','--qq', action="store_true", help="Blah",dest="q")

options, args = parser.parse_args()
```

Is there anyway to combine all these options:

```
python test.py -tbq
```

And get this result:

```
options.q  = True

options.t  = True

options.b  = True
```

Comment: ... it *already* does that! `argparse` provides the same functionality out-of-the-box too. -1 for not even trying to run your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options can be combined as you want. The program run with `-tb`

```
import optparse, sys 
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage='python %prog -t -b -q',
                           prog=sys.argv[0],
                                                      )   
parser.add_option('-t','--tt', action="store_true", help="Blah",dest="t")
parser.add_option('-b','--bb', action="store_true", help="Blah",dest="b")
parser.add_option('-q','--qq', action="store_true", help="Blah",dest="q")
options, args = parser.parse_args()

print options
```

produces

```
{'q': None, 'b': True, 't': True}
```

Comment: Awesome, I should have tried that before. I didn't see any ref to that in the documentation..